# Xcode changes tint of an image

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

I have encountered an unexplainable difficulty. I've got a certain bunch of images in my app and Xcode makes some of them a bit darker. An image may have its normal tint when the app is launched on Retina simulator and be darker when launched on non-Retina simulator, while another image behaves vice versa - normal on Retina and darker on non-Retina. the problem is not only for simulator, launching the app on a device leads to the same weird things. Have you ever experienced such a problem? Any ideas? Thanks a lot in advance

[image]

this is a shot from Retina. you see that two images at right and at left are bit lighter. this is normal color. the rest is darker

Comment: Do you have different images or retina? I.e do you have @2x and normal images?

Comment: Where did the images come from? Photoshop? Do you have separate @2x images? Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: Yes, i have @2x and normal ones. The images have been made in Photoshop. I can show screenshot but i'm afraid the difference in tints is gonna be hardly seen here. Wait a second please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly the embedded colour profile within the image. Try exporting the images for web and devices, rather than saving, or changing the colour profile to RGB (rather than adobe rgb).

Comment: oh, i'm sorry, didn't understand your explanation, can you please explain in more detail?

Comment: Within an image there is a header that tells the device showing it how to display it. One of the items that is added, particularly in photoshop is the 'Colour profile'. This tells the display how to map the colours in the file to the colours in an output device (for the difference in an LCD / CRT / printer etc). iOs (and the mac in general) will honour this flag and remap the colours to match the profile provided. You can set it in photoshop (but I can't remember where offhand!)

Comment: hmmm but one image is shown normally in ordinary iPnone and gets darker on Retina only

Comment: Assuming they have a different colour profile. Select Edit->Assign Profile and set 'don't color manage'. If you export with web and devices don't set 'Convert to sRGB' and ensure 'Embed Color Profile' is off. Try that, check if it is different.